# Bitcoin ATM paid out to a phone number, how can the funds be retrieved?

Tags: private-key, lost-transactions, bitcoin-atm

A friend was trying to send me bitcoin using a Bitcoin ATM, she sent the funds to "her phone number" instead of my wallet QR code. The ATM indicated that Bitcoin was sent, but my friend doesn't even have a wallet address. It seems like a wallet address was generated for her and we don't know how to retrieve this bitcoin back, can you help?

Comment: Did she get a transaction ID (64-character hex code)?  You can look it up on a site like http://blockchain.info and see what address the coins were actually sent to.

Comment: Did the ATM provide a receipt? What's on it? (Do not share any exact numbers or codes on the receipt. Just generally describe what's on it!)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the ATM operator?

Answer (score 1):

> **it seems like a wallet address was generated for her**

This seems most likely to me. An ATM should not allow the destination/receiving address to be empty or to contain something that is not a valid bitcoin-address (e.g. a phone number would be rejected)

A phone number might be requested for an online custodial wallet service with two-factor authentication (2FA) - if so you'd need to find out the URL of the service, and the corresponding username and password or other credentials.

If your friend doesn't have a printed receipt with some details on it, it is likely that the money is now forever inaccessible.

I would

- try to find a printed receipt
- contact the ATM owner (although I would not expect them to be able to help)
- visit the ATM with your friend and try to recreate what happened with the minimum possible amount of money as a test.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to receive or send bitcoins using an ATM, but I think there are special account statements that you can get from an ATM (you can also fund anything there). I sometimes call an ATM to check my account but always make myself a number to [receive sms online uk](https://quackr.io/temporary-numbers/united-kingdom). It turns out that no one will know my real number (anti-spam for advertisers). I think bitcoin can be topped up when you have accurate information about the possibilities of using the currency elsewhere.